# TikZ graph node wobble

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

## Is there a way to align nodes by baseline in TikZ graphs?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout]
  \node {aligned?}
    child {%
      node {yes}
    }
    child {%
      node {no}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

In the example above, the `yes` node is taller because the `y`, and the nodes seem to be centered vertically, so the baseline of the `no` node ends up lower than the `yes` node's baseline. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Usually this is done by giving the nodes some `text depth`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout,nodes={text depth=0.3ex}]
  \node {aligned?}
    child {%
      node {yes}
    }
    child {%
      node {no}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ilka had exactly the same problem while working on "The Programming Language Pascal".

Comment: @ScumCoder Yes. You can also find it right under **Part IV
Graph Drawing** on p. 409 of pgfmanual v3.1.3.

Comment: +1: I did not encounter `text depth` so far. Is this something new?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, it has been there for ages.

Comment: pgfmanual also mentions `text height`, which would be useful if e.g. the `no` was capitalized. It seems like setting `text depth` to 0 still doesn't clip from underneath, but you need a larger value of `text height` to avoid clipping. Is there a way to find out a good distance to set it to? I guess you can try different values until you get it right, but you'd have to repeat for different font sizes.

Comment: @BaltazárRadics I do not know the "perfect way". Apart from `text height` there is also the `baseline` option, which is useful for inline nodes. I do not know if there is a simple way to use it here (but I also did not try). Personally I would use `forest` for such trees which solves most of these issues either automatically or easily.